# Show the elements in the set are unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am having a hard time figuring out how to prove that the set below has all unique elements when p is a prime that is not 2. I know that {$0^1 \mod p, 1^2 \mod p, ... , ((p-1)/2)^2 \mod p$} are all unique. Is this enough? How else could I show this? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x, y \in \{ 0, \ldots, \frac{p-1}{2} \}$, $x \neq y$,

suppose on the contrary that

$$-(x^2+1)  \equiv -(y^2+1) \mod p$$

Then $$x^2+1  \equiv y^2+1 \mod p$$

Then $$x^2  \equiv y^2 \mod p$$

which contradicts your claim.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the help. I was very stuck on that one.

Comment: Because  $x^2\equiv y^2\pmod p\implies$ $ p|(x+y)\cdot |x-y|$ with $p>x+y>|x-y|\geq 0.$ So $x-y=0$. (else $p$ would be composite.)